# ESB doesn't return anything from the GET service failing with NPE

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've configured a proxy service to run some XSBRL validation stuff that accepts a get request amd return XML validation results. Here's proxy service configuration:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="XBRLValidationRESTService" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/example.xbrl/validation/xbrl?media=xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:10000/rest/xbrl" format="pox"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
  </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

In the log file I can see that the underlying service responds with expected response, however the client receives nothing back because ESB fails with NPE for some reason.

Request used from localhost:

```
curl -k  https://localhost:9443/services/XBRLValidationRESTService
```

Full log: http://pastebin.com/A5jB9wMF

What is the potential reason for that and how that could be fixed.

Thanks,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you run ESB with blocking transport? By default esb uses NIO transport and the port is 8280. your proxy service url, will be;

```
http://localhost:8280/services/XBRLValidationRESTService
```

Rather putting log full state, use descriptive logs to identify message paths,

Comment: You must be a magician! Changed to NIO and all wonderfully worked. Thanks, appreciate your answer. But agree that logs could be more informative, not just NPE and that's it..